# Re-set timestampt font in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I've updated Ubuntu to 22.04 and now the font used for time stamps in org-mode is bigger than other fonts (headlines, text, tags, etc.). This is making the file look very awkward and it's difficult to align.

What controls that particular setting, and how do I make that font the same as others?

EDIT: Upon request, this is the output of `desribe-face` `org-date`:

```
Face: org-date (sample) (customize this face)

Documentation:
Face for date/time stamps.

Defined in ‘org-faces.el’.


           Family: unspecified
          Foundry: unspecified
            Width: unspecified
           Height: unspecified
           Weight: unspecified
            Slant: unspecified
       Foreground: Purple
DistantForeground: unspecified
       Background: unspecified
        Underline: t
         Overline: unspecified
   Strike-through: unspecified
              Box: unspecified
          Inverse: unspecified
          Stipple: unspecified
             Font: unspecified
          Fontset: unspecified
           Extend: unspecified
          Inherit: fixed-pitch
```

Comment: Add the output of `M-x describe-face RET org-date RET` to your question.

Comment: @NickD I just edited the question. The "sample" there matches the style used by the timestamps.

Comment: If I set the `Height` of `fixed-pitch` to 0.9, it seems to produce the effect desired, but I don't know if that's a conceptually correct solution.

Comment: Can you also add what `C-u C-x =` gives you on a character in normal text, as well as on a character in a time stamp? The interesting things are the font and the face, but please add all of the output anyway.

Comment: Instead of changing the height of `fixed-pitch`, can you change the height of `org-date`? Unless `fixed-pitch` is too high in other contexts, you probably want to leave it alone. Maybe you can check a table in Org mode: the face is `org-table` and it also inherits from `fixed-pitch` by default I believe.

Comment: @NickD I have a report table at the end of my agenda and, when I reset fixed-pitch to its default value, it becomes huge. I think, between org-date and fixed-pitch, the latter is the one to change.